# Can SuperDuper backup/restore to a network drive on another macbook pro?

Tags: network, backup, superduper

I want to use an older macbook pro for scheduled backups of my current macbook pro. I would prefer to use something a little more user friendly/intuitive than Time Machine.
Can SuperDuper backup/restore my current system SSD to an external mechanical drive on another macbook pro on the network?

Comment: Did you check their website for features or contact the developer with your question?

Comment: TM is about as friendly and intuitive as backups get! Use this disk. Done.